# Dependency Injection Access While Configuring Service Registrations in asp.net Core (3+)

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-identity

I have cases, where I want to configure services based on objects which are registered in the dependency injection container.
For example I have the following registration for WS Federation:

```
authenticationBuilder.AddWsFederation((options) =>{                
       options.MetadataAddress = "...";
       options.Wtrealm = "...";                
       options.[...]=...
});
```

My goal in the above case is to use a configuration object, which is available via the DI container to configure the WsFederation-middleware.
It looks to me that `IPostConfigureOptions<>` is the way to go, but until now, I have not found a way to accomplish this.
How can this be done, or is it not possible?

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer, which approach did you choose in the end? (Just wondering if my untested code works)

Comment: The latter, but I tested also the first one, however without accessing my DI object. With the first I also had a problem with registering, but I didn't mind, since the latter is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://andrewlock.net/simplifying-dependency-injection-for-iconfigureoptions-with-the-configureoptions-helper/ for the `I(Post)ConfigureOptions<T>` way, but I find that way too cumbersome.

I generally use this pattern:

```
// Get my custom config section
var fooSettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("Foo");

// Parse it to my custom section's settings class
var fooSettings = fooSettingsSection.Get<FooSettings>() 
    ?? throw new ArgumentException("Foo not configured");

// Register it for services who ask for an IOptions<FooSettings>
services.Configure<FooSettings>(fooSettings);

// Use the settings instance
services.AddSomeOtherService(options => {
    ServiceFoo = fooSettings.ServiceFoo;
})
```

A little more explicit, but you have all your configuration and DI code in one place.

Of course this bypasses the `I(Post)ConfigureOptions<T>` entirely, so if there's other code that uses those interfaces to modify the `FooSettings` afterwards, my code won't notice it as it's reading directly from the configuration file. Given I control `FooSettings` and its users, that's no problem for me.

---

This should be the approach if you do want to use that interface:

First, register your custom config section that you want to pull the settings from:

```
var fooSettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("Foo");
services.Configure<FooSettings>(fooSettingsSection);
```

Then, create an options configurer:

```
public class ConfigureWSFedFromFooSettingsOptions 
    : IPostConfigureOptions<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation.WsFederationOptions>
{
    private readonly FooSettings _fooSettings;

    public ConfigureWSFedFromFooSettingsOptions(IOptions<FooSettings> fooSettings)
    {
        _fooSettings = fooSettings.Value;
    }

    public void Configure(WsFederationOptions options)
    {
        options.MetadataAddress = _fooSettings.WsFedMetadataAddress;
        options.Wtrealm = _fooSettings.WsFedWtRealm;
    }
}
```

And finally link the stuff together:

```
services.AddTransient<IPostConfigureOptions<WsFederationOptions>, ConfigureWSFedFromFooSettingsOptions>();
```

The configurer will get your `IOptions<FooSettings>` injected, instantiated from the appsettings, and then be used to further configure the `WsFederationOptions`.

Comment: I needed indeed the IPostConfigureOptions., IConfigureOptions as shown in your example will not do, but the rest worked like a charm, thanks a lot.